# Fetching name and email from a web page

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to fetch data off from a [Link](http://ae.bizdirlib.com/node/946273). I want to fetch name/email/location/etc content from the web page and paste it into the webpage. I have written the code for it always when i run this code it just stores a blank list.

Please help me to copy these data from the web page.

I want to fetch company name, email, phone number from this Link and put these contents in an excel file. I want to do the same for the all pages of the website. I have got the logic to fetch the the links in the browser and switch in between them. I'm unable to fetch the data from the website. Can anybody provide me an enhancement to the code i have written.

Below is the code i have written:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlwt

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

# 0 wait until the pages are loaded
browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it

browser.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493") # Load page
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2 > a")

#print link
for link in links:
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.PAGE_UP)
#tree = html.fromstring(link.text)
    time.sleep(5)

companyNameElement = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".content.clearfix>div>fieldset>div>ul>li").text 
companyName = companyNameElement 
print companyNameElement
```

The Html code is given below

```
<div class="content">
<div id="node-946273" class="node node-country node-promoted node-full clearfix">
<div class="content clearfix">
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation" itemscope="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Company Information</legend>
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="float:right; width:340px; vertical-align:top;">
<br/>
<ul>
<li>
<strong>Company Name</strong>
: 
<span itemprop="name">Sabbro - F.Z.C</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

when i use it it gives me a error that `list' object has no attribute 'text'`. Can somebody help me to enhance the code and make it work. I'm kind of like stuck forever on this issue.

Comment: When you want to add information to a problem you've already posted on SO, the thing to do is to edit your original question. Posting a new question is not okay.

Comment: @Louis: Sorry, pretty new to stack overflow... Did not know about it.. Have done it now already. Will see to it the next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
companyNameElement = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".content.clearfix>div>fieldset>div>ul>li").text 
companyName = companyNameElement 
print companyNameElement
```

find_elements_by... return a list, you can either access first element of that list or use equivalent find_element_by... method that would get just the first element.

Comment: I tried to just get the element now but now it says unable to locate the element. I'm just looking to locate a few elements like company name/email/etc. and paste it into excel. Could you just help me find the exact element on the site.. I get the same element just looking for more clarification.

Comment: please post the html code from which u r trying to locate the company name/email etc.

Comment: @igniteram : I have added the html code by editing the question.